# Spark - provide extra parameter to udf

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a spark scala udf in order to transform MongoDB objects of the following shape:

```
Object:
    "1": 50.3
    "8": 2.4
    "117": 1.0
```

Into Spark ml SparseVector.
The problem is that in order to create a SparseVector, I need one more input parameter - its size.
And in my app I keep the Vector sizes in a separate MongoDB collection.
So, I defined the following UDF function:

```
val mapToSparseVectorUdf = udf {
  (myMap: Map[String, Double], size: Int) => {
    val vb: VectorBuilder[Double] = new VectorBuilder(length = -1)
    vb.use(myMap.keys.map(key => key.toInt).toArray, myMap.values.toArray, size)
    vb.toSparseVector
  }
}
```

And I was trying to call it like this:

```
df.withColumn("VecColumn", mapToSparseVectorUdf(col("MapColumn"), vecSize)).drop("MapColumn")
```

However, my IDE says "Not applicable" to that udf call.
Is there a way to make this kind of UDF that can take an extra parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Udf functions would require columns to be passed as arguments** and the `columns` passed would be *parsed to primitive data types* through *serialization* and *desirialization*. Thats why **udf functions are expensive**

If `vecSize` is *an Integer constant* then you can simply use `lit` *inbuilt function* as

```
df.withColumn("VecColumn", mapToSparseVectorUdf(col("MapColumn"), lit(vecSize))).drop("MapColumn")
```

Comment: Thank you. Which package should I import to use lit function? IDE says that it cannot resolve it

Comment: Ah, found it: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf, lit}

Comment: great to hear that you found it yourself @DaniilAndreyevichBaunov :)

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
def mapToSparseVectorUdf(vectorSize: Int) = udf[Vector, Map[String, Double]](
  (myMap: Map[String, Double]) => {
    val elements = myMap.toSeq.map {case (index, value) => (index.toInt, value)}
    Vectors.sparse(vectorSize, elements)
  }
)
```

Usage:

```
val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    ("1", Map("1" -> 50.3, "8" -> 2.4)), 
    ("2", Map("2" -> 23.5, "3" -> 41.2))
)).toDF("id", "MapColumn")

data.withColumn("VecColumn", mapToSparseVectorUdf(10)($"MapColumn")).show(false)
```

NOTE:

Consider fixing your MongoDB schema! ;) The size is a member of a SparseVector, I wouldn't separate it from it's elements.

Comment: .. which would then be used as follows: `df.withColumn("VecColumn", mapToSparseVectorUdf(vecSize)(col("MapColumn")))`

Comment: added sample usage!

Comment: I was considering changing my schema this way. But it would be inconvenient using such schema in my NodeJS server. Thank you for suggestion